# addEventListener to dynamically added html tags in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I would like to generate in the html code of my Angular component N pair of `<p> item_{1..N} </p> .. <pre> json_data{1..N} </pre>`
Such that `pre` N tags are initially hidden, and they expand when someone `click`s its upper `item_${i}`.

I tried adding javascript code inside the html to set the `innerHtml` but it didn't work. So I moved to do it in the Angular component.

The following code successfully generates the N (50) items, but no listeners are attached although I tried calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

```js
@Component({
  ....
})

export class X implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ...
  @ViewChild('my_div') myDiv ? : ElementRef;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.generateItems();
  }

  generateItems() {
    let str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      str += '<div #some_tag_${i}><p>item_${i}</p></div>';
      str += '<div #another_tag_${i}><pre>$json_data[i]</pre></div>';
    }
    // Assume that we have <div #my_div></div> in the html template of this component.
    this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML = str;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    // Trying with plain js document.* functions.
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      const someTag = document.getElementById(`some_tag_${i}`);
      if (!selfLinkElem) {
        continue;
      }
      someTag.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const anotherTag = document.getElementById(`another_tag_${i}`);
        if (!anotherTag) {
          return;
        }
        if (anotherTag.style.display === 'none') {
          anotherTag.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          anotherTag.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried putting the ElementRef in the constructor, but this does not generate the N items in the first place, hence the subsequent code does not work as well:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('some_tag_1');
  if (el) {
    // this block is never exercised.
    el.addEventListener('click', some_function);
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Comment: But why would you generate the elements this way? Perhaps there is a better way to generate the elements.

Comment: Suggestions are more than welcome. I tried generating it by a script in the html but it didn't generate anything.

Comment: I recommend to check [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)